# android seekbar widget

Tags: android, seekbar

I have a seekbar in android app to capture the values that ranges from 10-90. What is the java code for capuring the values.

please help
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

public class seekbar extends Activity {

```
private SeekBar seekBar;
private TextView textView;
private int newProgressValue,currentProgress=10;
private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences ;
private String Key_PROGRESS = "key_progress";
private String PREFERENCE_PROGRESS = "preference_progress";
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCE_PROGRESS , Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    currentProgress = sharedPreferences.getInt(Key_PROGRESS, 10);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.radious);
    seekBar=(SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekbar);
    seekBar.setMax(90);
    seekBar.setProgress(currentProgress);
    textView.setText(String.valueOf(currentProgress));

    seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            newProgressValue = seekBar.getProgress();
            currentProgress = newProgressValue ;
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
            editor.putInt(Key_PROGRESS, newProgressValue);
            editor.commit();

        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                boolean fromUser) {
             textView.setText(String.valueOf(seekBar.getProgress()));

        }
    });


} }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `seekbar.onSeekbarChangeListener` for this.See this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener.html) for official java doc..