# Is it possible to create Seekbar Widgets?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, widget, android-seekbar

Is it possible to create a Seekbar widget for Android, how could I create it? I try to find some information about it in the internet but I couldn't find anything.
In advance thanks for your answer!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4745639/android-seekbar-widget

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

activity_main.xml

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"  
        android:layout_width="match_parent"  
        android:layout_height="match_parent"  
        >  

        <SeekBar  
            android:id="@+id/seekBar1"  
            android:layout_width="match_parent"  
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"  
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"  
            android:layout_marginTop="39dp" />  

    </RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnSeekBarChangeListener{  
        SeekBar seekBar1;  
        @Override  
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  

            seekBar1=(SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);  
            seekBar1.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);  
        }  
        @Override  
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,  
                boolean fromUser) {  
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"seekbar progress: "+progress, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
        }  
        @Override  
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {  
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"seekbar touch started!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
        }  
        @Override  
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {  
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"seekbar touch stopped!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
        }  
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But would your presented code not be a normal Seekbar inside the app? I am looking to create a widget (which I can drop on the Homescreen.